# How do I specify seperate workspace.xml files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, centos

I'm opening two instances of the same project in IntelliJ on CentOS. I followed the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889413/start-two-instances-of-intellij-ide)

That worked great, but now I have two instances of IntelliJ that are sharing the same workspace.xml file, which means that they both constantly think that the file is changing out from underneath them(which it is). Is there a way to specify where the workspace.xml file is located when you launch IntelliJ? That way I could have a separate workspace.xml for each instance.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I have exactly the same issue.