# Running multiple CLion instances simultaneously

Tags: jetbrains-ide, clion

From the looks of it, it seems that either one cannot open multiple CLion instances or that option is turned off by default.

Is there a way to open several CLion instances simultaneously? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: Other JetBrains IDE can open other projects in separate frames/windows but it still will be only 1 app. I would think that CLion can do the same here.

Answer (score 2):

To open a project in a new window:
"File" -> "Open.." -> select your project -> "OK" -> "New Window"

Comment: While this openes another project window, it's not a new instance, because you can not compile in oboth of them independently.

Answer (score 1):

This question [Start two instances of IntelliJ IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889413/start-two-instances-of-intellij-ide/28435362) is about intelij, but the same procedure applies to CLion.

In my case I created a separate instalation and configured the idea.properties with a separate copy of the configuration files.

Note: This is for people that do need to create a new instance. In my case we are two people working on the same user on remote machine, so we cannot share the same instance.