# Is possible open the same project on two instances of Intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I have a distributed project and I need debug two nodes of my app on the same time. For this I wish open two instances of Intellij, it is possible ?

Comment: I need to use this because when I remote desktop all existing instances still exist but are not useable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is this topic about starting two instances of IntelliJ [Start two instances of IntelliJ IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889413/start-two-instances-of-intellij-ide)

It is not possible with one instance from my experience

Answer (score 16):

just open each one from different folder level.

For example: Project A has 2 folders (one inside another) and inside the 2nd folder there is code. Then open one instance from folder 1 and another instance from folder 2.

Open each instance by choosing open in new window..simple.

Comment: Works (IntelliJ 2023.1.5) and has the advantage that you get a proper project window with left and right sidebar windows (which you _don't_ get if you simply move an editor tab to a new window).

Answer (score 4):

Just for new people who navigate here.  You could just drag & drop the code you want outside android studio.

Comment: This is what i want.

Comment: Best answer in the whole universe.

Comment: But it won't have toolbars and menus. // You can use 3 monitors each to edit a specific file, but if you need the menu or toolbar, you need to go to a specific monitor, because those only exist once. A bit annoying sometimes.

Comment: Although this allows using multiple screens to write code, it does not allow debugging multiple instances of the same application

Answer (score 3):

I found this really helpfull:

> You can split the editor view vertically/horizontally, this will
>   display the same file in both splits, then you can drag one of the
>   tabs outside of the IDE to create a float editor window.
>
> Another way to open multiple editors for the same file is to select
>   the file in the Project view and press Shift+Enter.

Source: Serge Baranov response in [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000366324-How-to-Open-Multiple-Windows-Views-Viewing-the-Same-File-Project-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. One easy thing you can do is open two different major *versions* at the same time (e.g. 2015 and 2016) or if you have Ultimate edition, you can also install community edition and have both of those open at the same time. Or if you're using community edition, you could install a trail of ultimate just this one time :)

Of course the downside to the second approach is that you may not have some plugins you need for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to checkout the same project twice. e.g. A and B. That way we can switch the branches in two different instances of PHPStorm and debugging will be easy too.